# Can I select the boundary element according to regionmark?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

The tutorial of Finite Element Generation gives a example on the useage of `RegionMark`

```
sh = 0.2;
sh2 = 0.02;
sw = 0.3; 
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., sh}, {1., 1.}, {0., 
     1.}, {0., sh + sh2}, {sw, sh + sh2}, {sw, sh}, {0., sh}}, 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
       5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {3, 
       8}}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.1, sh/2}, 1, 0.001}, {{0.1, sh*2}, 
     2}}];
mesh[
 "Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[FaceForm[Green]], 
    Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}]]
```

which will produce 
[image]

The boundary element of mesh can be obtained by using `mesh["BoundaryElements"]`. I want to know can I obtain the boundary element of the region with the prescribed `RegionMark`. For example, for the figure shown above, I want to only obtain the boundary element of the bottom green region.

Comment: A question on this topic, How can I define Neumann boundary condition on the boundary between Green and Red regions? The boundary condition I want is that the electric displacement in y direction must follow `εgreen . Eygreen = εred . Eyred`

Comment: @NavidRajil, ask a question with a specific example. I suspect you do not need that at all. Also, have a look at the [Partial Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients section in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html). That shows a variable coefficient / multiple material domain solution.

Comment: @user21, please refer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165160/neumann-boundary-condition-on-a-boundary-inside-the-region).

Comment: Is my answer of any use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. You'd need to add element markers to the boundary mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
sh = 0.2;
sh2 = 0.02;
sw = 0.3;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., sh}, {1., 1.}, {0., 
      1.}, {0., sh + sh2}, {sw, sh + sh2}, {sw, sh}, {0., sh}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {3, 8}}
      , {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4}
      ]}];
```

Note the element markers in the boundary elements. I have added 4 markers:

```
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Blue, Orange}]]
```

[image]

Once you generate the mesh the boundary markers will be propagated to the new boundary elements in the full mesh:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.1, sh/2}, 1, 0.001}, {{0.1, sh*2}, 2}}];

Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], 
      FaceForm[]]}]], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Blue, Orange}]]]
```

[image]

You can inspect the generated markers:

```
Union[Join @@ ElementMarkers[mesh["BoundaryElements"]]]
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

In addition to the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) you probably also want to look at the [ElementMesh Visualization tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html).