# Neumann boundary condition on a boundary inside the region

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I want to solve the Laplace equation in 2 different medium in 2D, each with its own dielectric constant. This is the extremely simplified geometry. The problem is the same error (which you will find out in the end!) for my more complex geometry in 3D.

I start with defining the region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {.5, 0.}, {1., 0.}, 
{1., 1.}, {.5, 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1,2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5},
{5, 6}, {6, 1}, {2, 5}}]}];

bmesh["Wireframe"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

The result is:

[image: Plot of bmesh]

[image: plot of meshes of the mesh]

You can see there is a boundary at `x==0.5` and the mesh of the region is made considering that there is a boundary at `x==0.5`.

My attempt to solve Laplace equation with only Dirichlet boundary condition is as follows, note that I just modified the [wolfram's FEM tutorial example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#938383864) for my problem:

```
\[Epsilon]r = If[x <= .5, {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}}, {{10., 0.}, {0., 10.}}]
op = Inactive[Div][-\[Epsilon]r.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}]
\[CapitalGamma]D = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1., x == 0.],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 2., x == 1.], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == .1, 0. <= x <= .5 && y == 0.],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 0.5 <= x <= 1. && y == 0.],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 0. <= x <= .5 && y == 1.],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == .1, .5 <= x <= 1 && y == 1.]}

\[CapitalGamma]N = NeumannValue[2, .45 < x < 0.55 ]; (*This is 
simplified condition. I will explain the B.C. I have in mind at the 
end.*)

ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, \[CapitalGamma]D}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

The result ***without using the Neumann condition*** is:

```
Show[ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], bmesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image: Contour plot of the solution with only Dirichlet boundary condition]

However, when I use Neumann boundary condition on the boundary at `x==0.5` this happens:

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == \[CapitalGamma]N, \[CapitalGamma]D}, u, 
{x,y} \[Element] mesh]

(*NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where 
x==0.5 was True, so NeumannValue[2,x==0.5] will effectively be 
ignored.*)
```

Please note that the Neumann condition that I have in my mind for the boundary at `x==0.5` is

```
\[Epsilon]r(*for x < 0.5*)*D[u[x,y],x] == \[Epsilon]r(*for x > 0.5*)*D[u[x,y],x]
```

and

```
D[u[x,y],y](*u[x,y] for left side of the region i.e. x < 0.5*) == 
D[u[x,y],y](*u[x,y] for right side of the region i.e. x > 0.5*)
```

I appreciate your help to resolve this issue and correctly implement the Neumann boundary condition at `x==0.5`.

P.S.

My attempt to solve the problem by solving for 2 function each with dirichlet boundary only on their own side also did not work. You can see that I made 3 types of attempts to set the Neumann conditions and non worked:

```
\[Epsilon]1 = 1;
\[Epsilon]2 = 2;

eq1 = Inactive[Laplacian][\[Epsilon]1 u1[x, y], {x, y}]
eq2 = Inactive[Laplacian][\[Epsilon]2 u2[x, y], {x, y}]

\[CapitalGamma]D2 = {DirichletCondition[u1[x, y] == 1., x == 0.], 
DirichletCondition[u1[x, y] == 1., 0. < x < .5 && y == 0.], 
DirichletCondition[u1[x, y] == 1., 0. < x < .5 && y == 1.],
DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == 2., x == 1.], 
DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == 2., 0.5 < x < 1. && y == 0.], 
DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == 2., .5 < x < 1 && y == 1.]}

\[CapitalGamma]N21 = Inactive[NeumannValue][D[\[Epsilon]2 u2[x, y], x], 
x == .5];(*type 1*)
\[CapitalGamma]N22 = Inactive[NeumannValue][D[\[Epsilon]1 u1[x, y], x], 
x == .5];(*type 1*)

{u1fun, u2fun} = NDSolveValue[{eq1 == \[CapitalGamma]N21(*((\[Epsilon]2 
D[u2[x,y],x])/.x\[Rule].5)(*type 2*)*), 
eq2 == \[CapitalGamma]N22(*((\[Epsilon]1 D[u1[x,y],x])/.x\[Rule].5)
(*type 2*)*), \[CapitalGamma]D2
(*,((\[Epsilon]1 D[u1[x,y],x])/.x\[Rule].5)==((\[Epsilon]2 
D[u2[x,y],x])/.x\[Rule].5)(*type 3*)*)}, {u1, u2}, {x, y} 
\[Element]mesh]
```

Errors for type 1 (click on images to see them large):

[image: Error 1, type 1]

[image: Error 2, type 1]

[image: Error 2, type 1]

and errors for type 2 (click on images to see them large):

[image: Error 1, type 2]

[image: Error 2, type 2]

and  errors for type 3 (click on images to see them large):

[[image: Error 1, type 3]

[image: Error 2, type 3]

[image: Error 3, type 3]

[image: Error 4, type 3]

[image: Error 5, type 3]

Comment: A few questions: 1) What is the direction of the normal of the inner boundary? 2) You expect the derivative at `x+epsilon` and `x-epsilon` to be the same but not generally at `x<1/2` and `x>1/2`, right?

Comment: Does this help you: `xepsi = 10^-4;
((\[Epsilon]r*Derivative[1, 0][ufun][x, y]) /. {x -> (1/2 - xepsi), 
   y -> 1/2})
((\[Epsilon]r*Derivative[1, 0][ufun][x, y]) /. {x -> (1/2 + xepsi), 
   y -> 1/2})`

Comment: @user21, Numerically, yes. That is why I came up with double potential solution. One potential for left side where only boundary conditions of left side are used for it and vise versa for the right side (this is exactly how one can solve this electro magnetic problem analytically with one extra boundary condition which is potential will vanish at `x->infinity` for left side potential and it will vanish at `x-> -infinity` for the right side potential). In addition,  to your second comment, the condition you are imposing works only fro one point, while I want it to be true for `0=<y=<1`

Comment: Can you share a link to an example in a book, paper other FEM software where something like this has been done. I still do not quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user21, Classical Electrodynamic by Jackson, look for dielectric sphere in constant electric field.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that, when you don't specify the internal Neumann boundary condition, `NDSolve` gives precisely the solution of your **real** problem (looks like a miracle !).

Lets look at that.

Here is the code. As you can see, there no internal boundary conditions. (I have refined the mesh)

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
"Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {.5, 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {.5, 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1,2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5},{5, 6}, {6, 1}, {2, 5}}]}];

gr00=bmesh["Wireframe"];

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh,MaxCellMeasure-> 0.0001];
gr01=mesh["Wireframe"];

Row[{gr00,gr01}] //Style[#,ImageSizeMultipliers->.7 {1,1}]&

\[Epsilon]r = If[x <= .5, {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}}, {{10., 0.}, {0., 10.}}];
op = Inactive[Div][-\[Epsilon]r.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x,y}];
\[CapitalGamma]D = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1., x == 0.],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 2., x == 1.], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == .1, 0. <= x <= .5 && y == 0.],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 0.5 <= x <= 1. && y == 0.],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 0. <= x <= .5 && y == 1.],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == .1, .5 <= x <= 1 && y == 1.]};

\[CapitalGamma]N = NeumannValue[2, .45 < x < 0.55 ]; (*This is simplified condition. I will explain the B.C. I have in mind at the end.*)

ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, \[CapitalGamma]D}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];

Show[ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], bmesh["Wireframe"],ImageSize->200] 

Plot[{ufun[.499, y]-ufun[.498, y], 10(ufun[.502, y]-ufun[.501, y])},{y,0,1},
PlotLegends-> {"\[Epsilon]r D[u[x,y],x] for x = 0.498","\[Epsilon]r D[u[x,y],x] for x = 0.501"},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue}]

Plot[{ufun[.499, y]-ufun[.499, y-0.01], (ufun[.501, y]-ufun[.501, y-0.01])},{y,0,1},
PlotLegends-> {" D[u[x,y],y] for x = 0.498"," D[u[x,y],y] for x = 0.501"},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue}]
```

[image]
[image]

Here are :
- epsilon X the normal derivative
- the tangential derivative
just before and after the boundary x == 0.5

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andre. Now, that I see your answer (+1) I have heard the question of OP in different variants before. I think something like this should be in the documentation perhaps. What I fail to understand is why would one want to specify a Neumann value at the inner boundary. Why does one thing that this might be necessary? Do you have an idea how some can come to that conclusion?

Comment: @user21 Yes, I have a very precise idea of what's happening. The OP wants to 
 solve the Maxwell equations for electrostatics when the dielectic constant of the material suddenly jump (= is discontinuous). Maxwell says : 1) the tangential electric field E stays continuous 2) the normal of the electric field multiplied by epsilon stays continuous (equivalently D is continuous, where D=epsilon X E)

Comment: Ah, and from there the thought is that this needs to be enforced by a internal boundary condition.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me logical.

Comment: Nevertheless I don't understand the "miracle"

Comment: @user21 FYI A long time ago, I have taken your example in the documentation and turned it with a angle of 45°degree, to see if it still works. And it works ! [see here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34898036#34898036)

Comment: [related to my last comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34879868#34879868)

Comment: dear Andre, thanks for the effort, but what I am looking for is the following: 
    Plot[(\[Epsilon]r[[1, 1]] D[ufun[x, y], x] /. y -> .5) /. x -> i, {i, 0.45, .55}]

Comment: dear Andre, thanks for the effort, but what I am looking for is the following: `Plot[(\[Epsilon]r[[1, 1]] D[ufun[x, y], x] /. y -> .5) /. x -> i, {i, 0.45, .55}]`. I mean, the electric field in the x direction at the left side times its epsilon, must be equal to electric field in the x direction at the right side times its epsilon! what you are doing in your last 2 plots is you are showing me that electric field at each side close to boundary changes by how much. I want `ufun[.499, y]-10 ufun[.501, y] = 0` for any y. and so the typical try gives a jump!

Comment: I meant `D[ufun[x, y],x]/.x->.499 - 10 D[ufun[x, y],x]/.x->0.501 = 0`, the plot I stated at the beginning of my comments clearly shows the jump. Besides, I do not want to rely on miracles to solve the problem. The geometry I am trying to solve is a metallic cone in air above a dielectric and I can not rely on miracles in such complex geometries! However, I appreciate the time you put into it.

Comment: I take some of what I said back!!! it seems you are right Andre. but still, I have problem with the miracle part!!!